# Set the default Blend Type

Tags: video-sequence-editor

When I add any strip to Blender's Video Sequence Editor, the default `Blend Type` is `Cross`.

Is it possible to change the default to `Alpha Over`?

Comment: I think you'll have to replace the *Add movie strip* operator with one of your own, which sets the blend_type.

Comment: I guess I would have to also replace the `sequencer.scene_strip_add`, `sequencer.image_strip_add`, and  `sequencer.effect_strip_add` operators in addition to `sequencer.movie_strip_add`.

Comment: I have submitted a patch at https://developer.blender.org/D786 which changes the default blend type to Alpha Over.

Comment: @MutantBob Did that patch ever get merged?  This is still bugging the crap out of me two years later.

Answer (score 2):

You could get a script writer to make a add strip effect option. The Transform Addon currently creates a transform strip upon key press. So it is possible.

Currently over at the BA forum, user "snu" is actively developing a VSE script that might add this function for you. http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?338598-Addon-WIP-VSE-Quick-functions-Snaps-Fades-Zoom-Parenting-Titling-Play-speed

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to change the default type (without modifying the source code and making a custom build).

Comment: Do you not think there's any way to devise a workaround?  I was about to put a bounty on this question because I use the VSE a lot and I'm losing a few seconds here and there having to switch to `Alpha Over` for each strip.