# VSE: Change blend mode for multiple strips (via Python)

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor, blend-modes

Blender VSE imports default to CROSS as blend mode ([Set the default Blend Type](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13538/set-the-default-blend-type))
Multiple strips cannot be edited simultaneously via the Strip Properties' "Edit Strip".

I was not able to find information on whether the VSE selection can be used from Python (e.g. a "selected" property or method), only `active_strip`:

https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.SequenceEditor.html#bpy.types.SequenceEditor

If the strips in question share e.g. a prefix, they can be modified like so via the Python console:

```
>>> for strip in D.scenes["Scene"].sequence_editor.sequences_all:
...     if strip.name.startswith("myimage"):
...         strip.blend_type="ALPHA_OVER"
```

Is there another way, or can the selected strips be accessed via the Python API?